# Facebook Graph API, Post not working

Tags: php, facebook

I have my php app working fine, performing some other Graph API functions.

However, the following line:

```
$ret = $facebook->api("/1036102643/posts", "post", array('message'=>'This is a test 
message', 'caption'=>'test message'));
```

Produces:

Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request. thrown in /home/content/html/idvault/php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1106

Why am I getting this error?  Am I missing required fields (but the API doesn't mention any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the js sdk its /me/feed or /a_group_id/feed

```
$ret = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", array('message'=>'This is a test 
message', 'caption'=>'test message'));
```

Comment: Of course it’s ../feed – that’s what the docs _clearly_ state.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, is it protocol to ding a noob on FB development?  Looking at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ I was able to create an event.  Looking at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/, it was unclear that I had to create the post object through the feed.  Albeit, I will go RTFM.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts describe how to create feed items in general resp. posts in particular.